# jQuery looking for something else than "append"

Tags: jquery, text, append

This should be a relatively easy question to answer, currently in my code I have this:

```
$('#news').append(news_data);
```

but its not working as I want it to. I need the opposite of append which also allows html. I've tried ".text" but it didn't work as intended and I tried ".html" and it didn't work as intended either (it displayed only one result whereas append displayed all of the available results).

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking for, jQuery can append, insert, and replace content very easily.

Comment: Define "the opposite of append."  You've mentioned a few times that things "didn't work as intended" but what you haven't described is what you actually intend.

Comment: According to docs (http://api.jquery.com/append/) `append()` allows HTML tags to be included. What exactly do you want to achieve ?

Comment: Show your news_data.  It may be encoded or something that causes the html appendation to work incorrectly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The opposite of append would be prepend

Try:

```
$('#news').prepend(news_data);
```

This will add the new items to the beginning of the container instead of the end.

Answer (score 0):

Append an element with the text inside:

```
$('#news').append($('<div>').text(news_data));
```

Now each text is added as a block in itself and doesn't just continue the previous text. You can also style the elements inside, so that you for example get a bit of margin between the texts.